# how to call codeigniter helpers or php functions in mustache.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, mustache

hi i am working on mustache.php with codeigniter it is parsing mustache tag really nice now how can i use CI helpers or php functions with in mustache tags like

```
    {{ anchor("http://www.google.com","Google") }}

//php function

    {{ date() }}
```

i have tried mustache helpers but no luck as per this post [github mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/pull/82)

i this case i have to add extra opening and closing mustache tags. which i don't want just passing function in tags and get output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call functions directly in your Mustache template (logic-less templates, remember?)

```
{{ link }}
{{ today }}
```

Instead, this functionality belongs in your rendering context, or your ViewModel. At a minimum, this means preparing your data in advance:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'link'  => anchor('http://www.google.com', 'Google'),
    'today' => date(),
);

$mustache->loadTemplate('my-template')->render($data);
```

An even better approach is to encapsulate all of the logic required for `my-template.mustache` in a ViewModel class, lets call it `MyTemplate`:

```
<?php

class MyTemplate {
    public function today() {
        return date();
    }

    public function link() {
        return anchor('http://www.google.com', 'Google');
    }
}

$mustache->loadTemplate('my-template')->render(new MyTemplate);
```

Comment: its ok but when we have to put anchor in loop to make it more dynamic and passing parameters, right now parameters are static. it will create links in this case we have to lot of code on controller all data processing will happen on controller and really few stuff on view with mustache as compare to dwoo or smarty they can call function on view with in template tags, even for existing function of php you have to do double effort can function with in class methods or call in array

Comment: Yes. That's on purpose. That's part of the "logic-less template" paradigm. Mustache does not allow passing parameters to functions. It does not allow calling functions which are outside the rendering scope. This is intentional, and it is considered a feature.

Comment: This argument doesn't make any sense for PHP. Lower casing or title casing a string is absolutely something that belongs in the view (and in most mustache implementations, you can do this eg {{foo.upcase}} in ruby...). Given that scalar types are not classes in PHP, having no way to make simple presentation related modifications to a string kneecaps the system in this platform, and causes problems that simply aren't present even in other mustache implementations. I shouldn't have to decide every possible presentation of a string that might be used in a separate file...